# RecyclerView and Adapter data updates

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is a question about RecyclerView internal behavior for someone that knows its mechanics or is willing to dig into the source code. I’d like an answer backed up by references to the source.

## Original question

*(scroll down to ‘In other words’ for a more focused question)*

I need to understand how `notify*` actions (for example, `notifyItemInserted()`) are enqueued. Imagine I have an adapter backed up by this list:

```
ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "three", "four");
```

I want to add the values `zero` and `two`, that are missing.

#### Example 1

```
list.add(1, "two");
// notify the view
adapter.notifyItemInserted(1);


// Seconds later, I go on with zero
list.add(0, "zero");
// notify the view
adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

This is pretty straightforward and clear, nothing to tell.

#### Example 2

But what if the two actions are very close to each other, and there’s no layout pass in between?

```
list.add(1, "two");
list.add(0, "zero”);
```

**What should I do now?**

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(1);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

Or maybe

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(2);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

? From the adapter perspective, the list immediately switched from `one, three, four` to `zero, one, two, three, four` so the second option seems more reasonable.

#### Example 3

```
list.add(0, “zero”);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
list.add(2, “two”);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(...)
```

What about it now? `1` or `2` ? The list was updated immediately after, but I am sure there was no layout pass in between.

#### Question

You got the main issue, and I want to know how should I behave in these situations. The real case is that I have multiple asynchronous tasks ending up in an `insert()` method. I can enqueue their operations, but:

1. I don’t want to do that if there’s already an internal queue, and there surely is
2. I don’t know what happens if two actions happen without a layout pass in between, see Example 3.

## In other words

To update recycler, 4 actions must happen:

1. I actually alter the data model (e.g. insert something into the backing array)
2. I call `adapter.notify*()`
3. Recycler receives the call
4. Recycler **performs** the action (e.g. calls `getItem*()` and `onBind()` on the adapter) and lays out the change.

It’s easy to understand this when there’s no concurrency, and they happen in sequence:

```
1. => 2. => 3. => 4. => (new update) 1. => 2. => 3. => 4. ...
```

Let’s see what happens between steps.

- Between **1.** and **2.**: I would say it is the developer responsibility to call notify() immediately after having altered the data. That’s OK.
- Between **2.** and **3.**: This happens immediately, no issue here.
- Between **3.** and **4.**: This does **not** happen immediately! AFAIK. So it perfectly possible that a new update (steps **1** and **2**) comes between steps **3** and **4** **of the previous update**.

I want to understand what happens in this case.
How should we behave?
Should I ensure that step **4** of the previous update did took place before inserting new stuff? If so how?

Comment: For example 2: you can use notifyitemrange method.   Example 3: use notifyiteminserted(2)

Comment: @Divyesh my tests are showing a different story, so I’d like an answer backed by reference to code. Also, I used small indexes (0 and 1) to make things clear, but please treat them as random (e.g. 0 and 25). Also, if you look at the source, you’ll see that `notifyItemInserted(position)` is always treated as a `notifyItemRangeInserted(position, 1)`. Which one you use does not make a difference here.

Comment: For multiple operations, i think you should make all insert first then use notifydatasetchnged

Answer (score 8):

I thought about similar questions before, and I decided:

1. If I want to insert more than 1 item directly to end of list and
   want to get a animation for all, I should:

   ```
   list.add("0");
   list.add("1");
   adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(5, 2); // Suppose there were 5 items before so "0" has index of 5 and we want to insert 2 items.
   ```
2. If I want to insert more than 1 item directly to end of list, but
   want to get separated animation for each inserted item, I should:

   ```
   list.add("0");
   list.add("1");
   adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
   mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // before this happens, Be careful to call other notify* methods. Never call notifyDataSetChanged.
           adapter.notifyItemInserted(1); 
       }
   }, mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().getAddDuration());
   ```
3. If I want to insert more than 1 item to different position of list,
   similar as 2.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 4):

So lets start from little intro to RecyclerView works with notify items. And works pretty simple with other list of saved ViewGroup items (ListView for ex.)

RecyclerView has Queue of View Items which already drawn. And doesn't know about any your updates, without calling `notify(...)` methods. When you added new Items and notify RecyclerView, it starts cycle for checking all Views one by one.

```
RecyclerView contains and drawn next objects
View view-0 (position 0), view-1 (position 1), View-2 (position 2)

// Here is changes after updating
You added Item View view-new into (position 1) and Notify
RecyclerView starts loop to check changes
RecyclerView received unmodified view-0(position-0) and left them;
RecyclerView found new item view-new(position 1)
RecyclerView removing old item view-1(position 1)
RecyclerView drawing new item view-new(position 1)

// In RecyclerView queue in position-2 was item view-2, 
// But now we replacing previous item to this position
RecyclerView found new item view-1 (new position-2)
RecyclerView removing old item view-2(position 2)
RecyclerView drawing new item view-1(position 2)

// And again same behavior 
RecyclerView found new item view-3 (new position-3)
RecyclerView drawing new item view-1(position 2)

// And after all changes new RecyclerView would be
RecyclerView contains and drawn next objects
View view-0 (position 0), view-new (position 1) view-1 (position 2), View-2 (position 3)
```

It's just main flow of working notify functions, but what should know all this actions happens on UI Thread, Main Thread, even you can calling updating from Async Tasks. And answering you 2 Question - You can call Notify to the RecyclerView as much as you want, and make sure, you action would be on the correct Queue.

RecyclerView works correct in any usage, more complicated questions would be to your Adapter work. First of all, you need to synchronize you Adapter action, like adding removing items, and totally refuse of index usage. For example, it's would be better for your Example 3

```
Item firstItem = new Item(0, “zero”);
list.add(firstItem);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.indexOf(firstItem));
//Other action...
Item nextItem = new Item(2, “two”);
list.add(nextItem);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.indexOf(nextItem))
//Other actions
```

**UPDATE |**

Related to  [RecyclerView.Adapter Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html), where you can see functions same with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. And where this `RecyclerView.Adapter` invokes  child items with `android.database.Observable` extensions, see more [About Observable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Observable.html). Access to this Observable Holder is synchronized, until View Element in RecyclerView release usage.

See also RecyclerView from support library version 25.0 Lines 9934 - 9988;

Comment: My question is exactly what happens if I modify the backing array (`list.add`) and notify the RecyclerView **while** (or **before**) the RecyclerView was able to perform the last notify() action (e.g. the loop you are talking about)

Comment: @natario I already answered, even you using handler task, to start you action, hundred per second with notifying, Recycler Queue is synchronized  with updating data. And will do all actions one by one.

Comment: With respect to the question (see above, I added a section to make the question clear), you are telling me that step 4 takes place immediately, synchronously after step 3. Could you back this up with a reference to the source code? It seems to me that this is not true. See `android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper` class.

Answer (score 3):

It should not be a problem if you make multiple updates between layout passes. The `RecyclerView` is designed to handle (and optimize) this case :

> RecyclerView introduces an additional level of abstraction between the
>   RecyclerView.Adapter and RecyclerView.LayoutManager to be able to
>   detect data set changes in batches during a layout calculation. [...]
>   There are two types of position related methods in RecyclerView:
>
> - layout position: Position of an item in the latest layout calculation. This is the position from the LayoutManager's
>     perspective.
> - adapter position: Position of an item in the adapter. This is the position from the Adapter's perspective.
>
> These two positions are the same **except the time between dispatching
>   adapter.notify* events and calculating the updated layout**.

In your case the steps are :

1. You update the data layer
2. You call `adapter.notify*()`
3. The recyclerview record the change (in `AdapterHelper.mPendingUpdates` if I understand the code correctly). This change will be reflected in [ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()), but not yet in [ViewHolder.getLayoutPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition()).
4. At some point the recyclerView apply the recorded changes, basically it reconcile the layout's point of view with the adapter's point of view. It seems that this can happen before the layout pass.

The **1.**, **2.**, **3.** sequence can happen any number of times as long as **2.** immediately follows **1.** (and both happen on the main thread).

```
(1. => 2. => 3.) ... (1. => 2. => 3.) ... 4.
```

Comment: `and both happen on the main thread` why should 1 happen on the main thread? Apart from this, I’ll be back to you soon to ask for a clarification.

Comment: otherwise there is no garanty that 2) occur imediately after 1). there is a delay. I think the actual sequence should be 0) gather the data (on a background thread)  then post the result (via an event bus or a handler) and do 1) and 2) atomically on the main thread

Comment: i.e. the data, as seen by the adapter should change at once, and the switch should happen on the main thread

Comment: Yes, I meant that `as long as 2 immediately follows 1 (and both happen on the main thread)` would be more correct as `as long as 2 immediately follows 1 (and 2 happens on the main thread)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
Item firstItem = new Item(0, “zero”);

list.add(firstItem);

adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.indexOf(firstItem));

//Other action...

Item nextItem = new Item(2, “two”);

list.add(nextItem);

adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.indexOf(nextItem))
```